# Hide a form element on select change

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to hide a form element unless a particular dropdown value is selected; here is my code so far, however it is not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('txt_ccode').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 'GB') {
                document.getElementById('txt_postcode').style.display="block";
            }
            else {document.getElementById('txt_postcode').style.display="none"; }

    }); 
});
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you are using jQuery, the inner show and hide logic and be simplified like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#txt_ccode').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 'GB') {
                $('#txt_postcode').show();
            } else {
                $('#txt_postcode').hide();
            }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: what a numpty i am! all your answers are correct! only after i managed to reference jquery as well! cant beleive i forgot to include the jquery library!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
$('txt_ccode')
```

You probably either want:

```
$('#txt_ccode')
```

or

```
$('.txt_ccode')
```

Depending on what you've set your element's id and/or class attribute to.

Also, you could re-write your code to make it a bit more concise:

```
$('#txt_ccode').change(function() {
    $('#txt_postcode').toggle($(this).val() === 'GB');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify why it isnt working. What error messages do you get, using a debugger such as Firebug. Perhaps document.ready, or the change function never gets run. Or the value is not what you expect.

Also, since you are using jQuery its best practice to completely use it. So instead of document.getElementById i'd use `$('#txt_postcode')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $('select').on('change', function( e ) {
      var val = $('select option:selected').val() // get the value from a dropdown select
      if( val == 'GB' )
      {
          $('element').show()
      }
      else
      {
          $('element').hide()
      }
   })
});
```